# Is it possible to use a keras ModelCheckpoint that minimizes both val_loss and test_loss?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, callback

Can `ModelCheckpoints` (or any combination of callbacks) in keras be used to save models that minimize multiple variables (in my case, validation loss and test loss) at the same time instead of monitoring just one?

Comment: Any feedback on the proposed solution? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, through `LambdaCallback`, see [keras](https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback) or [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LambdaCallback) docs. It allows you to create custom callbacks like this:

```
custom_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epochs, logs: model.save('best_test_loss') if logs['test_loss'] > logs['val_loss'] else model.save('best_val_loss'))

(...)

model.fit(...,
          callbacks=[custom_callback])
```